# Recursive function not returning expected result

Tags: python, recursion

I am just practising with recursive programming... and I am testing this piece of code in Python:

```
def sum(f,a, b):
    def iter(a, result):
        if (a>b):
            print result
            return result
        else: iter(a+1, result+a)
    return iter(a, 0)

id = lambda x: x

def sumInts(a, b): return sum(id, a, b)

print sumInts(1,10)
```

the printout is None... debugging it, I found the var: result computes the sum of ints right before returning the last loop, but the value returning from the function is None...

What does it fail?
--- just learning Python, so, please, be kind with me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You missed a return statement :)

```
def sum(f,a, b):
    def iter(a, result):
        if (a>b):
            print result
            return result
        else:
            # Need a return here
            return iter(a+1, result+a)
    return iter(a, 0)

id = lambda x: x

def sumInts(a, b):
    return sum(id, a, b)

print sumInts(1,10)
```

Comment: Is it pythonic to put a function definition inside another function?

Comment: @mauve pretty much, yeah

Comment: to Mauve... I am studying high-order functions, currying and anonymous functions, and I am working on some examples and exercises using Python... and it works,,, thanks Sid